# "Download of update package failed." when trying to upgrade to 3.6.2

Tags: upgrade, joomla-3.6

My current version is 3.6.0. When I was trying to directly upgrade to 3.6.2, I always get this error message:

> Download of update package failed.

I've done upgrading on the same site several times but have never encountered this problem. I checked the configuration.php file, and /tmp folder is set to 0755. Also I looked at the error log, there is no information regarding the failure.

What could possibly be the cause and where can I get more detailed error message than just "download failed"? I host this site on my own virtual server.

Comment: Have you tried performing the update manually but uploading and installing the update package?

Comment: Not yet. I am obsessed by this issue and if I upgrade the other way I won't be able to reproduce the scenario

Answer (score 5):

You can download the Joomla upgrade package and place it in the **tmp** folder using FTP.

Then run the installation again. It will work.

Comment: This worked for me.

Comment: This also worked for me.  You don't need to extract the archive folder just place the update package in the tmp folder and click the update button.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your Joomla Update Component is updated, you might have to <kbd>Clear Cache</kbd> and <kbd>Find Updates</kbd> under **Extensions** → **Manage** → **Update**.

[image: Joomla Update Component Update]

If you have Akeeba Backup installed, make sure it's also updated, just in case.

Comment: I've every extension updated, nothing in "Warnings" section, but still it won't update from 3.6.0 to 3.6.2.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when trying to update Joomla from 3.6.2 to 3.6.3. On the first instance, I uploaded the zipfile and could execute the update that way. So for all you folks out there that want the easy way: simply download the update zipfile and do the update that way.

Anyway, on the second 3.6.2 instance, I finally ended up patching the code to follow redirects. The update to 3.6.3 succeeded! And off course, it overwrote my patched code. :-))

What I basically did is patch the JHttpTransportStream.request() function in the file libraries/joomla/http/transport/stream.php

```
#BNN DEBUG BEGIN
//      OLD CODE
//      return $this->getResponse($headers, $content);
//      NEW CODE
        $response = $this->getResponse($headers, $content);
        if($response->code==302 && $options['follow_location']==1) {
            //received HTTP/302 Redirect, find "Location:" header
            error_log('BNN DEBUG Location='.$response->headers['Location']);
            return $this->request($method, new JUri($response->headers['Location']), $data, $headers, $timeout, $userAgent);
        }
        return $response;
#BNN DEBUG END
```

Answer (score 1):

File /administrator/components/com_joomlaupdate/models/default.php

Search this string:

`if (!$result || ($result->code != 200 && $result->code != 310))`

Add new codes:

`if (!$result || ($result->code != 200 && $result->code != 310 && $result->code != 303 && $result->code != 302))`

That is all.

(The same solution for the new version 3.6.5)

Answer (score 0):

I did a little debugging and it looks like the file that is being downloaded - Joomla_3.6.2-Stable-Update_Package.zip  is behind a redirection.  On line 315 of com_joomlaupdate/models/default.php I have:

```
// Download the package
$result = $http->get($url);
```

where i get $result->code = 302 but no file gets downloaded.  There needs to be some error checking here but I don't know enough about Joomla to say what.  Does anyone know how to have this get request to then follow the redirect and download the file as I think that would be the correct fix.

I currently can't add a comment here so I wrote this instead.